# How do I properly reset the clip in cairocffi?

Tags: python-3.x, cairo

I am trying to write a module for myself for doing some simple drawing with cairocffi to make using the package a bit less cumbersome. However, I seem to have run into some trouble with properly implementing clipping. Specifically, I am having trouble properly resetting the clipping region.

I wrote an example Python script, whose result should be a PostScript file with:

- 1 red circle (`circle_1`)
- 1 black line from the bottom left to the top right of the circle (`line1`)
- 1 black line from the top left of the image to the bottom right of the image (`line2`)

Instead of `line2` extending from corner to corner, though, it is still being clipped by the previous call to `clip()`.

Here's the example script:

```
import cairocffi as cairo
from math import pi

fig_w, fig_h = 237.6, 237.6
test_surf = cairo.PSSurface('test.ps', fig_w, fig_h)
temp_surf = cairo.PSSurface('temp.ps', fig_w, fig_h)

line1 = cairo.Context(temp_surf)
line1.move_to(0, fig_h)
line1.line_to(fig_w, 0)
line1.set_source_rgb(0,0,0)
line1.stroke()

circle_1 = cairo.Context(test_surf)
circle_1.arc(fig_w/2, fig_h/2, fig_w/4, 0, 2*pi)
circle_1.close_path()
circle_1.set_source_rgb(1,0,0)
circle_1.stroke_preserve()
circle_1.set_source_surface(temp_surf)
with circle_1:
    circle_1.clip()
    circle_1.paint()

line2 = cairo.Context(test_surf)
line2.reset_clip()
line2.move_to(0, 0)
line2.line_to(fig_w, fig_h)
line2.set_source_rgb(0,0,0)
line2.stroke()
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. This seems to be how the cairocffi documentation would suggest that it should be done (i.e., see [`reset_clip()`](https://pythonhosted.org/cairocffi/api.html#cairocffi.Context.reset_clip) and [`save()`](https://pythonhosted.org/cairocffi/api.html#cairocffi.Context.save)).

If anyone can point out what I'm doing incorrectly, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Rejecting edits then doing the same thing isn't appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I'm brand new to SE. I haven't actively rejected any edits. I've only seen the suggestions during/after submitting my own. I'll make sure to check for edit suggestions before doing my own in the future.